# Javascript: Set the focus on a special character after inserting it in a textarea by using a shortcut

Tags: javascript, textarea, keyboard-shortcuts

I use a shortcut to insert a certain character into a text area. After insertion, the cursor is directly behind the character. I would like the focus to remain exactly on this character. Anyone have an idea for this?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible code sample?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to post a code sample. If you position the cursor inside the word "text", let's say between "t" and "ext":

`t|ext`

if you press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>, javascript will insert an emoji in place and will set the cursor position back to where it was before.

```js
const txt = document.getElementById('txt')

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {

    // ONLY WHEN COMBINATION IS CTRL + B
  if ( ((!e.ctrlKey) || e.key === "Control") || e.key !== "b") { return }
  
  // GET CURRENT CURSOR POSITION
  let oldCursorPos = txt.selectionStart
  
  // GET TEXT BEFORE CURSOR POSITION
  let output = txt.value.substring(0, oldCursorPos)
  
  // INSERT EMOJI IN BETWEEN
  output += ':)'
  
  // GET TEXT AFTER CURSOR POSITION
  output += txt.value.substring(oldCursorPos, txt.value.length)
  
  // ASSIGN TEXT TO TEXTAREA
  txt.value = output
  
  // SET CURSOR POSITION TO THE OLD POSITION
  txt.selectionStart = oldCursorPos
  txt.selectionEnd = oldCursorPos
})
```

```html
<textarea id="txt">text</textarea>
```